# Unable To See Master Pages While Adding A Page In The Project

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to add a .aspx page in the project , but while adding the .aspx page i am not getting the option to choose existing master pages.

Comment: Does right clicking on the particular master page you want and selecting "Add Content Page" work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why it is not visible; if you cannot set it, simply add it later manually to the [`@Page` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) of your page.

It's simple:

```
MasterPageFile="~/Path/To/My/MasterPage.master"
```

E.g. on top of your ASPX page, write something like:

```
<%@ Page 
    Culture="auto"
    UICulture="auto"
    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
    Title="The Title of your Page" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Path/To/My/MasterPage.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="MyPage" 
    %>
```

In addition, if you want to access the derived type of your master page, use the [`@MasterType` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx):

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Path/To/My/MasterPage.master" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug with VS,  try save the project with your master page then close and reopen VS.

If not as Uwe Keim mentioned above it is really easy to add the master page manually.